# Querying data using Entity Framework from dynamically created table

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

**TLDR; How do I read data from a table using Entity Framework, when the table name isn't known at compile-time?**

There is an external system that processes a bulk of information, and then creates a new table for each batch run, and stores some data in that table. The column layout of these new tables are known before-hand, so I have generated an ADO.NET Entity Data Model *(edmx file)* from an existing database, where there is a table with the exact same column layout.

The original table in that database is called `ResultTableTemplate`, so the entity class representing that table is also called `ResultTableTemplate`.

I am trying to figure out how to use my ADO.NET Entity Data Model to read from those dynamically created tables, and getting back `IEnumerable<ResultTableTemplate>`. What I have done so far is this:

```
public IEnumerable<ResultTableTemplate> GetResultsFromTable(string tableName) {
    using (var context = new WorkdataEntities()) {
        var table = context.CreateQuery<ResultTableTemplate>("SELECT " +
            "ALL_THOSE_COLUMN_NAMES... " +
            "FROM " + tableName;

        var query = from item in table select item;

        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

When I run the query, I get a `System.Data.EntitySqlException` with the following message:

> 'ResultTable419828' could not be resolved in the current scope or
>   context. Make sure that all referenced variables are in scope, that
>   required schemas are loaded, and that namespaces are referenced
>   correctly. Near member access expression, line 1, column 225.

`ResultTable419828` is the value of `tableName`

I have tried `tableName + " AS ResultTableTemplate"` but it did not help.

Is there a way forward for me, or will I have to do this without the help of Entity Framework?

**EDIT:** I realize now that the query text I am writing is not passed all the way down to the underlying SQL Server instance, but gets interpreted by Entity Framework which returns an `ObjectQuery<ResultTableTemplate>` instance, so it looks for `ResultTable419828` among the auto-generated `DbSet` instances of the Context.

Still, is there a way for me do achieve what I need to do?

**EDIT:** Thanks [Ladislav Mrnka](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8897140/891667). Now, I do this:

```
public IEnumerable<ResultTableTemplate> GetResultsFromTable(string tableName) {
    using (var context = new WorkdataEntities()) {
        var query = context.ExecuteStoreQuery<ResultTableTemplate>("SELECT " +
            "ALL_THOSE_COLUMN_NAMES... " +
            "FROM " + tableName;

        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that is creating an EntityQuery, not a database query.  Therefore the FROM is a DbSet not a database table.

Comment: `CreateQuery<T>()` returns an `ObjectQuery<T>` - and I see now that your are correct. The query is not against a database table, but a DbSet. Do you think there is a way to do what I need to do here?

Comment: We use a DbConnection with SqlQuery<T> to get a scalar value from the database.  I didn't write that portion of our DAL, so I'm not entirely sure how it works, but you might be able to start there.

Comment: you were close....Use `context.ExecuteStoreQuery` instead of `context.CreateQuery`, because since it's a SQL expression, EF can execute the query on the database of the context and optionally return you a typed resultset if the structure is the same.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not directly possible. When you map entity to `ResultTableTemplate` you hardcode the name of the table for this entity. Entities can be mapped only once (per model) so at runtime every EF query for this entity always results in query to `ResultTableTemplate` table.

The only way to change is behavior is modifying mapping file (SSDL) at runtime which is quite ugly hack because it requires you to change XML file and reload it. You will have to build `MetadataWorkspace` manually every time you change the file. Building `MetadataWorkspace` is one of the most performance consuming operation in EF. In the normal run `MetadataWorkspace` is created only once per application run.

There is simple workaround. You know the table name and you know the table structure - it is fixed. So use direct SQL and use EF to materialize the result into your mapped entity class:

```
var table = context.ExecuteStoreQuery<ResultTableTemplate>("SELECT ... FROM " + tableName);
```

The disadvantage is that you cannot use Linq in this approach but your requirement is not very well suited for EF.

Answer (score 1):

Try this; :)

```
string tableName = "MyTableTest";

// Fetch the table records dynamically
var tableData = ctx.GetType()
                .GetProperty(tableName)
                .GetValue(ctx, null);
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate how you would query the table.