# Use same type against two identical tables in EF Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two tables, Users and TempUsers and I need to do operations on both of them. I already have my users type defined and I want to add it to the DbContext for both tables. Problem is, it either uses convention to map the type name to a table or using the TableAttribute with the table name specified. Either way I can't see how to add two dbsets mapping the type to different table names.

I could duplicate the type using either copy + paste or through a UserBase class and two derived User and TempUser classes. Both ways will work but really in the code I want to deal with Users and not have the complexity of Users and TempUsers in the code. After all it's the repository's responsibly to deal with where to put the user objects and the business logic shouldn't have to deal with it.

Advice would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

**[Explanation Based On Comments]**

*The reason I have two tables is because the TempUsers is to support a bulk import/update but though atomic transactions on each user. So externally some active directory export or some such will result in calling a service for each user. I have to create/update users and figure out what ones are not being imported but already exist in my database and then delete them. Would be much simpler to truncate the Users table and write directly to that but the Id's would be different and it would break all the links the users have to different tables, like shipping history for example.*

Comment: If the `Users` and `TempUsers` tables are completely identical and are meant to be so, it doesn't seem like a good design to have them in two separate tables to begin with. Why not have a `Users` table with an `IsTemporary` field. It seems that this approach would solve all the issues you mention in your question.

Comment: Why don't you use a boolean or enumerated attribute on the class to classify if the user is a temporary or not?

Comment: I agree with the IsTemp col as the best approach.  In fact, the latest version of EF Code First essentially does this by adding a "Discriminator" col or something like that.  However, I'm working in a situation where I have to have two different tables because I'm dealing with a vendor's application that I can't control and it is not smart enough to check an IsTemp col. But I can configure two scenarios to use two diff tables.

In this case a base class is the best way to go, I think. You'll still be able to get twice the bang for your buck in 95% of your code by coding against the base class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not possible. EF cannot map same class twice within same context. Your single `User` class can be only mapped to `Users` table or `TempUsers` table in single context type. You need either two user classes or two different context types (with different mapping configuration) - one providing access to `Users` table and second providing access to `TempUsers` table.

Answer (score 0):

This reminds me of my own question: [Querying data using Entity Framework from dynamically created table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896843/querying-data-using-entity-framework-from-dynamically-created-table)

Actually, you can use EF and `ExecuteStoreQuery` to retreive objects, but you cannot use the LINQ features of EF.