# Get entities by passing just the name of the entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection

I'm using entity framework, and I need to get a list of entities only by passing the name of the entity.

Example:

```
string tableName = "PRODUCT";

List<tableName> myList = (from prod in dbContext.tableName
                          select prod).ToList();
```

What I can't get to do, is that, using the table name (string) to make a EF query (or LINQ).

I'm trying to get this to work by using Reflection or EntityDataModel, but I just can't.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  There may be other ways besides macro substitution.

Comment: The way I need to work is this or lots of IF sentences.

I know there should be some easy way, just I don't have a clue from where I should start.

Comment: Please add more detail about what you want to do and where you're struggling. Do you have one piece of logic that would run on any IQueryable<T> but you need to get from typeof(T) => IQueryable<T>? Are you stuck in getting from table name => typeof(T)? Are you using code first?

Comment: No, I'm not using code first, I created my entity model from the database.

In my example tableName is a string and I can't get an entity object PRODUCT using the string that equals the name of the entity.

Comment: Suppose you could pass the table name by string, how would you want to capture the results of your query in the appropriate type?

Comment: That's the reason I don't wanna use SQL Syntax... I wanna get in a VAR type the result of a LINQ Query, then using reflection I can iterate through the properties of my object.

I managed to get something using GetType().GetProperties() or something like that, but I can't get into the type.

When I make a quick inspection to that object, I can get the properties but is more a thing from .Net compiler rather than having a explicit instruction to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896843/querying-data-using-entity-framework-from-dynamically-created-table)):

```
var table = context.ExecuteStoreQuery<ResultTableTemplate>("SELECT ... FROM " + tableName);
```

Comment: I don't wanna use SQL... i'd like to use LINQ syntax.